# I'm unable to display the hidden list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently new to javascript and whenever I change the items of the list in html example from engineer,pilot,technician if I select engineer onchange event must call a function in javascript which will display the hidden select list which contains division on which he works such as wing or engine division.

this is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function func(v) {
     if(v=="Engineer"){
     var y=document.getElementById("a");
     y.style.visibility : visible;
     }
   }
</script>
```

this is html

```
<select onchange="func(this.value)">
    <option>Please Select</option>
    <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
    <option value="Pilot">Pilot</option>
    <option value="Technician">Technician</option>
</select>
```

and my select list html which is hidden and wanted to display when I select 'Enginner' is

```
<select id="a" style="visibility : hidden">
   <option>select the division</option>
   <option>Wing Division</option>
  <option>Engine Division</option>
</select>
```

I'm doing something wrong in javascript code could you please help me

Comment: `y.style.visibility : visible;` this should throw an error on execution

Comment: Your code is full of issues, please use the console to make a debug!  I've already executed your code with the necessary fixes and everything has worked as expected.

Comment: `y.style.visibility = 'visible';`

Answer (score 1):

there were a mistake in your code ,
you can't set it like css properties (`:`) the  `y.style.visibility : "";` 
will throw an error .

so you can set visibility by `y.style.visibility = "";`
also you've to hide the combo if it's not equal to Engineer

```js
var y = document.getElementById("a");

function func(v) {

  if (v == "Engineer") {
    y.style.visibility = "";
  } else {
    y.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="func(this.value)">
    <option>Please Select</option>
    <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
    <option value="Pilot">Pilot</option>
    <option value="Technician">Technician</option>
</select>


<select id="a" style="visibility : hidden">
   <option>select the division</option>
   <option>Wing Division</option>
  <option>Engine Division</option>
</select>
```